# SDL2 Access violation reading location error when trying to use shift?

Tags: c++, sdl, keyboard-events

So I'm trying to make a keyboard handler for a side project that I'm making in SDL2. After searching around the web a bit for some help this is what I came up with.

```
bool Keys[322];
void init() override {
    for (bool i : Keys) {
        i = false;
    }
}

void update() override {

    if (CRS::event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
        Keys[CRS::event.key.keysym.sym] = true;

    }

    if (CRS::event.type == SDL_KEYUP) {
        Keys[CRS::event.key.keysym.sym] = false;

    }

    if (Keys[SDLK_w]) {
        Transform->Velocity.y = 0; //moves the player up
    }
}
```

This code above works fine most of the time, but the problem occurs whenever I try to use any keys SDL considers a modifier (such as left shift, capslock, ctrl, alt, etc). Whenever I even touch one of those buttons I get a Access violation reading location error. Can anyone tell me why that is? And if I wanted to use shift, capslock, etc how would I go about doing that?

Comment: What is the value of `CRS::event.key.keysym.sym` when the access violation occurs?

Comment: Any keyboard modifiers, so SDLK_LSHIFT, SDLK_CAPSLOCK, SDLK_LALT, SDLK_RALT, etc. However SDLK_w, SDLK_e and all other non modifers work.

Comment: What is the *numeric* value? You are using that value as the index to an array. Is it a valid index?

Comment: SDLK_w, etc are valid indexes, but as far as I know they don't have any real numeric values. Honestly I did find it odd how I could access the array like that, but it didn't break so I thought it would be fine if I kept it.

Comment: The *only* valid indices to an array are numeric values.

Comment: @ALPELA said values are very high (at least 1 billion, because bit 30 is raised).

Comment: Why are you using keycodes and not scancodes to begin with? Keycodes are only good for low-level *text* input. And scancodes do have consecutive values, so you'd be able to use them as array indices.

Answer (score 0):

So i've decided to scrap my code after realizing that this probably isn't how I want to implement what I wanted and used the SDL_GetKeyboardStates function instead, which worked like a charm.